# C# Type in Powershell without Type boxing/converting to System.MarshallByRefObject using CyberArk xAPI

Tags: c#, powershell, cyber-ark

I have a PowerShell script that is using Methods and types from a .NET dll.
After a redeployment of the script to another machine (Windows Server 2019), I get type conflicts.

For Example:

```
$myvar = Get-VaultClass
```

the type of $myvar should be [XAPI.VaultClass], but it is System.MarshallByRefObject.

The types and Namespace are available in the Script (using Import-Module)

The Question is, how can I prevent for the converting/boxing of types

Enrico